# Compute the Matrix-Vector

Tags: code-golf, math, array, matrix

Given an integer array of at least two elements, output the **Matrix-Vector** (defined below) of the array.

To compute the **Matrix-Vector**, first rotate through the size-`n` input array to create a matrix of size `n x n`, with the first element of the array following the main diagonal. This forms the matrix portion. For the vector, flip the input array vertically. Then perform normal matrix multiplication. The output vector is the result.

For example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

First, rotate the array two times to the right, to obtain `[3, 1, 2]` and `[2, 3, 1]`, then stack them to form a `3x3` matrix

```
[[1, 2, 3]
 [3, 1, 2]
 [2, 3, 1]]
```

Next, flip the array vertically to form the vector

```
[[1, 2, 3]    [[1]
 [3, 1, 2]  x  [2]
 [2, 3, 1]]    [3]]
```

Perform usual matrix multiplication

```
[[1, 2, 3]    [[1]    [[1+4+9]    [[14]
 [3, 1, 2]  x  [2]  =  [3+2+6]  =  [11]
 [2, 3, 1]]    [3]]    [2+6+3]]    [11]]
```

And the output is `[14, 11, 11]` or `[[14], [11], [11]]` (your choice of whether it's flattened or not).

#### Example #2

```
a = [2, 5, 8, 3]

[[2, 5, 8, 3]    [[2]    [[4+25+64+9]     [[102]
 [3, 2, 5, 8]  x  [5]  =  [6+10+40+24]  =  [80]
 [8, 3, 2, 5]     [8]     [16+15+16+15]    [62]
 [5, 8, 3, 2]]    [3]]    [10+40+24+6]]    [80]]

[102, 80, 62, 80]
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ṙJṚæ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4bmZSuG5msOmLv/Dh8WS4bmY//9bMiwgNSwgOCwgM10)

### Explanation

Firstly:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
\vec{v}_1 \\
\vec{v}_2 \\
\vec{v}_3 \\
\vec{v}_4 \\
\end{matrix}\right] \vec{x} =
\left[\begin{matrix}
\vec{v}_1 \cdot \vec{x} \\
\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{x} \\
\vec{v}_3 \cdot \vec{x} \\
\vec{v}_4 \cdot \vec{x} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

where \$\vec{v}_k\$ are **row** vectors and \$x\$ is a **column** vector.

This demonstrates that matrix multiplication is just dot product between rows and columns.

Then, \$\vec{v}_1\$ is actually \$\vec{v}\$ rotated \$0\$ to the right, and \$\vec{v}_k\$ is \$\vec{v}\$ rotated \$k-1\$ to the right, etc.

From another angle, \$\vec{v}_1\$ is \$\vec{v}\$ rotated \$n\$ to the left, and \$\vec{v}_n\$ is \$\vec{v}\$ rotated \$1\$ to the left, etc.

### How it works

```
ṙJṚæ.   input: z (a list of length n)
ṙJ      [rot(z,1), rot(z,2), ..., rot(z,n)] (to the left)
  Ṛ     [rot(z,n), ..., rot(z,2), rot(z,1)]
   æ.   [rot(z,n).z , ..., rot(z,2).z , rot(z,1).z] (dot product)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda x:[sum(map(int.__mul__,x,x[i:]+x[:i]))for i in range(len(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsIwEAC/sscsLoIVQQK@JIYQsdGFzTakLcTXx@Y0zBym/LbvolNPj2eXmF/vCM26dc8mx2JYt3MIeZcQqFFzbP2pOcseMS0VGFihRv3MRmY1DdH30WV0dyGYCK6e3IEbwX2ILfWYglAygv0P)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
def f(v):r=range(len(v));return[sum(v[i]*(v*2)[i+j]for i in r)for j in r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwEEX3nmJ2Teq4MCKIRS8SshBMdIpOy3Qa8PTRBNy9x4f3548@J3al3GOCZLI9y0Vu/IjmFfmndpCoq7Bf1rfJnkJvcu@sp@0Y0iRAQAxiK44NQytpXLTGYBZihYzQ7a4dtodNG/0eHR7C3xwe8VS9fAE)

Comment: `(v*2)[i+j]` nice trick

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
ms*VQ.>QdU
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ms%2aVQ.%3EQdU&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B2%2C+5%2C+8%2C+3%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
LḶN⁸ṙæ×W€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//TOG4tk7igbjhuZnDpsOXV@KCrP/Dh8WS4bmY//9bMiwgNSwgOCwgM10)

A function that returns a vertical array. As a full program it appears as if it returns a horizontal array. To return a horizontal array you'd do `LḶN⁸ṙ×⁸S€` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
DgGDÁ})ε*}O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJd3d5XBjrea5rVq1/v//RxvpKJjqKFjoKBjHAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
Most@FoldList[RotateRight,#,1^#].#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfN7@4xMEtPyfFJ7O4JDoovySxJDUoMz2jREdZxzBOOVZPWe1/QFFmXomCQ1p0tZGOqY6FjnFt7H8A)

*-9 bytes from @Not a tree*

Comment: It's shorter to use [Mathematica's own matrix multiplication](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) than to recreate it yourself: `Most@FoldList[RotateRight,#,1^#].#&`. (But nice trick using `Fold` instead of `Nest`!)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

```r
sapply(length(n<-scan()):1,function(i)c(n[-(1:i)],n[1:i])%*%n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzixoCCnUiMnNS@9JEMjz0a3ODkxT0NT08pQJ600L7kkMz9PI1MzWSMvWlfD0CpTM1YnLxpIx2qqaqnmaf43UjBVsFAw/g8A)

Comment: using `Map(function(i)c(n[-(1:i)],n[1:i])%*%n,length(n<-scan()):1)` is 3 bytes shorter; it just returns a list of matrices.

Comment: and a for loop `for(i in seq(n<-scan()))F=c(c(n[-(1:i)],n[1:i])%*%n,F);F[1:i]` is 61 bytes without returning a weird output format.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
f v=sum.zipWith(*)v.fst<$>zip(iterate tail$v++v)v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hzLa4NFevKrMgPLMkQ0NLs0wvrbjERsUOKKKRWZJalFiSqlCSmJmjUqatXaZZ9j83MTNPwVYhJZ9LQUGhoCgzr0RBRSFNIdpQx0jHOBZN0EjHVMcCKPwfAA)

For an input `v=[1,2]`

- `iterate tail$v++v` yields the list `[[1,2,1,2],[2,1,2],[1,2],[2],[],...]`
- `fst<$>zip l v` is the same as `take(length v)l` and yields `[[1,2,1,2],[2,1,2]]`
- `sum.zipWith(*)v` is mapped on each element and to yield the vector-matrix row product.

Comment: A lot smarter than my answer! I like `fst<$>zip l v` very much.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 17 bytes

```
{__,,\fm>\f.*::+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Oj5eRycmLdcuJk1Py8pKu/Z/XcL/aCMFUwULBeNYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 37 bytes

```
{..,({.)\+}[*]{[1$\]zip{~*}%{+}*}%\;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlf979aT09Ho1pPM0a7NlortjraUCUmtiqzoLpOq1a1WrsWSMZY1/6vS/gfbaRgqmChYBwLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda v:dot([roll(v,i)for i in range(len(v))],v)
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQ@74ix2TkNBmIsC9RDx1aDbRJCbXg19f3yl1P06HH39JTyP8tQJs2qzi7pYSNhaI5CIiCBz12TLtiI1q50Su6ZdArlxskF/P67sVFK0acPwxfhpFhWIn6Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
+/ .*~#\.1&|.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBW19BT6tOOUbPUK1GL5aLKzU5I19BwzpNU81OwVDBSMFYwRpImipYKBj//w8A)

### Explanation

```
+/ .*~#\.1&|.]  Input: array M
      #\.       Length of each suffix, forms the range [len(M), ..., 2, 1]
             ]  Identity, get M
         1&|.   For each 'x' in the suffix lengths, rotate left M  by 'x'
+/ .*~          Dot product with M
```

Comment: This is quite nice.  One question.  When you do `1&|.` aren't you bonding `1` to `|.`, creating a monad?  but then you use that monad with both a left and right arg, with the left one determining how many times it's applied.  What's going on here?

Comment: @Jonah It's a special form for `&`. When used as `u n&f v`, it is performing `(n&f)^:u v`. See the bottom of [bond](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampm) to see more parses of it.

Comment: ah, TIL.  is that something you use often?

Comment: @Jonah It's useful for golfing in many cases. In this case, it could have been done in an equal number of bytes using rank `#\.|."{]`, but I posted the shortest that I came up with first before trying alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```hs
f l=[sum$zipWith(*)l$drop i$l++l|i<-[0..length l-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwEED3fsUNGVqbBqsIDvYTnB2ODAFTc3iJRxNBxH@PdXB6PHgvuHz3zLXOwBPmZ1RvkguV0G46VtflIUCK@54/dBpwawz7dCsBeBitrf7lorDPMAHiqGGnYW81rjhoOP7ENk10lNYgOjlDKwulYuYO/mv9Ag)

*Saved one byte thanks to @Laikoni*

*Saved three bytes: `l++l` instead of `cycle l`*

Comment: You can save a byte with `zipWith(*)l$drop i$cycle l`.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 17 bytes

```
(↑¯1⌽(⍳≢)⌽¨⊂)+.×⍪
```

Explanation:

```
(↑¯1⌽(⍳≢)⌽¨⊂)+.×⍪

 ↑                      matrix format of
  ¯1⌽                   right rotate by 1 of
     (⍳≢)               the 1..[length N]
         ⌽¨             rotations of
           ⊂            the enclosed input
             +.×        inner product with
                ⍪       1-column matrix of input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave - <s>67</s> 48 bytes

*Thanks to Luis Mendo for shaving this code down by 19 bytes!*

*Note: This code can only run in Octave.  MATLAB does not support expressions inside functions that can create variables while simultaneously evaluating the expressions that create them.*

```
n=numel(a=input(''));a(mod((x=0:n-1)-x',n)+1)*a'
```

The original code in MATLAB can be found here, but can be run in any version of MATLAB.  This code is 67 bytes:

```
a=input('');n=numel(a)-1;a(mod(bsxfun(@minus,0:n,(0:n)'),n+1)+1)*a'
```

## Explanation

1. `a=input('');` - Receives a (row) vector from the user through standard input.  You must enter the vector in Octave form (i.e. `[1,2,3]`).
2. `n=numel(...);` - Obtains the total number of elements in the input vector.
3. `x=0:n-1`- Creates a row vector that increases from `0` up to `n-1` in steps of 1.
4. `(x=0:n-1)-x'` - Performs broadcasting so that we have a `n x n` matrix so that each row `i` are elements from 0 up to `n-1` with each element in row `i` subtracted by `i`.
5. `mod(..., n)+1` - Ensures that any values that are negative wrap around to `n` so that each row `i` contains the vector from 0 up to `n-1` **circularly** shifted to the left by `i` elements.  We add 1 as MATLAB / Octave starts indexing vectors or matrices with 1.
6. `a(...)` - Creates a `n x n` matrix where using (4), we access the correct indices of the input vector dictated by each value from (4) thus achieving the matrix we need.
7. `(...)*a'` - Performs matrix vector multiplication by transposing / flipping `a` to become a column vector prior to doing the multiplication.

## Example Runs

```
>> n=numel(a=input(''));a(mod((x=0:n-1)-x',n)+1)*a'
[1,2,3]

ans =

         14.00
         11.00
         11.00

>> n=numel(a=input(''));a(mod((x=0:n-1)-x',n)+1)*a'
[2,5,8,3]

ans =

        102.00
         80.00
         62.00
         80.00
```

---

## [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zzavNDc1RyPRNjOvoLREQ11dU9M6USM3P0VDo8LWwCpP11BTt0JdJ09T21BTK1H9//9oQx0jHeNYAA)

Comment: You can use implicit expansion instead of `bsxfun`. Defining `n` without `-1` saves a few bytes too. And if you restrict to Octave you can assign `a` and `0:n` to variables on the fly and [save some more](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zzavNDc1RyPRNjOvoLREQ11dU9M6USM3P0VDo8LWwCpP11BTt0JdJ09T21BTK1H9//9oQx0jHeNYAA). Also, come here more often!! :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo ah yes. I forget Octave has implicit expansion already supported. Also saving the variable inside the `input` function is a great trick. I didn't think it could support that. I've seen it only in C or C++ from my own experience. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll place your suggested changes as an edit soon. I have been busy, but I haven't made this a priority as this entry will surely never win in byte count.

Comment: @LuisMendo Changed. Thank you very much :) Got to understand the code as I was changing my explanation above.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 34 bytes

```matlab
@(a)a*toeplitz(a,shift(flip(a),1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjUTNRqyQ/tSAns6RKI1GnOCMzrUQjLSezACijY6ip@T9NI9pQR8FIR8E4VpMLyAGyTHUULMD8/wA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
mΣ§‡*´ṀKoṫ¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9odXNr//9tzqPCp@KAoSrCtOG5gEtv4bmrwqL///9bMiw1LDgsM10)

### Explanation

```
mΣ§‡*´ṀKoṫ¢  Implicit input, e.g. [1,2,3]
          ¢  Cycle: [1,2,3,1,2,3,...
        oṫ   Tails: [[1,2,3,1,2,3...],[2,3,1,2,3...],[3,1,2,3...]...
     ´ṀK     Replace each element of input with input: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
   ‡*        Vectorized multiplication (truncated with respect to shortest list)
  §          applied to the last two results: [[1,4,9],[2,6,3],[3,2,6]]
mΣ           Sum of each row: [14,11,11]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 79 bytes

Takes in an input array and outputs an array of the matrix vector

```
a=>(b=[...a],a.map(x=>([...b].reduce((m,n,i)=>m+=n*a[i],0,b.push(b.shift())))))
```

### Explanation

```
a=>(
    b=[...a],                    // copy the input into b
    a.map(x=>(                   // transform a into a new array
        [...b].reduce(           // copy b into a new array and reduce
            (m,n,i)=>m+=n*a[i],  // memo += the element in the array * the ith
                                 // element in a
            0,                   // start memo at 0
            b.push(b.shift())    // shift the first element in b to the end
                                 // not used by reduce, but performing this op
                                 // here saves a few bytes
        )
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 80 bytes

```
#(map(fn[_ c](apply +(map * c %)))%(iterate(fn[c](into[(last c)](butlast c)))%))
```

`iterate` produces an infinite sequence, but instead of using `(take (count %) (iterate ...))` to stop it I use `%` as an extra argument to `map`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 + 1 (-a) = 66 bytes

```perl
@o=@F;for(@o){$r=0;$r+=$_*$F[$i++%@F]for@o;say$r;unshift@F,pop@F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h39bBzTotv0jDIV@zWqXI1sBapUjbViVeS8UtWiVTW1vVwS0WKO2Qb12cWKlSZF2aV5yRmVbi4KZTkF/g4Fb7/7@RgqmChYLxv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91EwE)

Takes the input vector as space separated numbers.  Outputs linefeed separated numbers representing the result vector.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 126 bytes

```c
i,j;int*f(int*a,int n){int*r=malloc(n*sizeof(int));for(i=0;i<n;i++){r[i]=0;for(j=0;j<n;j++)r[i]+=a[j]*a[(j-i+n)%n];}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU3RisIwEHy@@4rgISRtPDyrIMTej4Q8hDTVDXUrafpi6bf3Norew87OzgyzbnN2bvkCdN3YeHYaUgP99@V3ARkUYCpantFKQoZiykesr7bresexGODu@0dECNX2kUO9VXBCBWUppqjB0J31QDuQHkjPcllbHUxhNQ8bKFGs0ag5@jRGZFHNS353tYC5mlkxfX5kkvyQ9N6wmk07eZBHWc3q4RQs@mHsEjktzym5F@TcInktX@l1I9n/mJV8xvXWvNjPm@3erDJUMi/VHw)

[An array may be represented in input as a pointer and length.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/48934)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 78 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(loop as i on(append x x)as y in x collect(reduce'+(mapcar'* i x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCgMhEEN/JTdntqduKezvTNWC4DqDWrBfv1WaS0LgJT6nZhdlVcNbK3psHanAEd2x48GgHU8cMzGCgqym0kETkfMVhAb/YWlI0EJiFkvAwOBZfdfWgNeco@9UY/j46G50inmpbpvM4Klr/S7/AQ)

Double the array (in this case a Lisp list) and iterate over the sublists with `i` (using `x`, through `y`, to stop the iteration). Then calculate the next element of the result by summing the result of multiplying each element of `x` with each element of `i` (again stopping when the shorter list is terminated).